# What size SSD would suffice for basic software-development / productivity?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

My friend is selling me his old MacBook (Glossy white finish with rounded edges and corners) cheap for a Mobile Development course I'm taking, but he's keeping the hard drive. So I'm thinking of buying an SSD off of somebody, and I'm not sure what the minimum size I would need.

I will have to install:

- Either keep Snow Leopard or Lion
- Xcode
- Whatever is needed to develop for Android and iOS
- Possibly some form of productivity suite (MSO or LibreOffice)

I barely have any experiences with Macs so I'm not sure how much space all of this would take up? I need to have a feel for the smallest SSD I can get

Answer (score 1):

A 128GB SSD would have enough room for what you list, with room to spare. A 256GB SSD, imho, would not cost that much more, and would give you more flexibility.

Be aware that the version of Xcode needed to develop for iOS 7 requires Mountain Lion, and ML may not support that machine. For learning or developing for iOS 6, Lion/Xcode 4 should be fine.

Comment: Damn. I was thinking 60GB would've been fine... And I'm buying 2nd hand SSDs, so they'll be a lot cheaper. I think the machine can only go up to Lion, but I'm pretty sure the school's not going to demand the latest Mac from everybody